# PostgreSQL Class Inheritance Json

Tags: database, postgresql, relational, class-table-inheritance

so with Postgres I am able to use the json-type column. So with classic relational database I use [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html), which seems cumberstone. Instead I can now use Postgres and just serialize my different subclasses into json and store them in a common table.

Does this approach have any considerable downsides or is it good to use (at least for "simple" use-cases)?

Comment: Inheritance means something different in databases than in OOP. I wrote about this a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074535/when-to-use-inherited-tables-in-postgresql/16169950#16169950 .

Comment: It'll be painful to query, inefficient to update, etc. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: @zxq9 Sorry I did not express this in my questions clearly, but I meant http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html and not Postgres inherited tables.

Comment: @CraigRinger thank you very much! I think my real question is: Since relational databases are cumberstone to use for modelling OOP-Inheritance, is using json the better of two evils?

Comment: @Tim json is better used for unstructured data which is not OOPs case. Using it to avoid proper normalization is very bad design.

Comment: Any updates on this? I want to do the same and there are no strong conclusions...